# Using Bootstrap with Stenciljs

Tags: ionic-framework, bootstrap-4, stenciljs

I have a PWA project in stencilJs. I wish to use bootstrap with it for responsive design. I have installed `stenciljs-bootstrap` npm package. Now when I am writing a sample text to check, Bootstrap doesn't work.

This is what i have installed - `npm i stenciljs-bootstrap`

My code on `app-contact.tsx`

```
export class AppContact {

  render() {
    return [
      <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  This is a primary alert—check it out!
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot. What needs to be done?

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you include to your project? You can't use just install with npm. You should include that.

Comment: Yes i even did npm i stenciljs-bootstrap but no effect

Comment: I never tried to import bootstrap but I think found your solve. Check this:> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-bootstrap-with-stencil-component/156128/4